# how to stop all the site animation when hover a button

Tags: javascript, css

I came a cross a problem which I tried pretty much everything without a solution.

i want to stop all the site(`.ball` , `.f_bl` , `.s_bl`, `.search`) animations when i hover the `.search_bar` (inside the form) Button, is it possible?

```css
.search{
   animation: colors_world 15s infinite
}  
.ball , .f_bl , .s_bl , .searchbar{
   animation: colors_world 15s infinite
}  
@keyframes colors {
  7.14%   {background: #E1140A;}
  21.43%  {background: #FF6A00;}
  35.71%  {background: #FEE600;}
  50%  {background: #6AC346;}
  64.27% {background: #46C8E1;}
  78.55% {background: #3E8DDD;}
  92.83% {background: #F04187;}
  116%   {background: #E1140A;}
}

@keyframes colors_world {
    7.14%   {color: #E1140A;}
    21.43%  {color: #FF6A00;}
    35.71%  {color: #FEE600;}
    50%  {color: #6AC346;}
    64.27% {color: #46C8E1;}
    78.55% {color: #3E8DDD;}
    92.83% {color: #F04187;}
    116%   {color: #E1140A;}
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="ball_cont"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="f_tr"></div>
  <div class="s_tr"></div>
  <div class="f_bl"></div>
  <div class="s_bl"></div>
</div>

<h1 class="hellosearch"> <span class="hello">hello</span><span class="search">search</span> </h1>

<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
  <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" placeholder="search..." class="bar">
  <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="button_search">
</form>
```

Comment: Just a side note, but I'm pretty sure you can't go over 100% in your `@keyframe` animation.  That's a % of completion through the animation, and you can't get to 116% through an animation

Answer (score 3):

The `animation-play-state: paused` exists in CSS, so we can just add that as a separate class we'll call `.paused`.  Now we can just add and remove that class to all the needed elements when we hover the mouse over an element, and then remove that class when the mouse leaves it.  I've set up the below example to do this when you hover over the `.button_search` element.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.button_search');
var animatedEls = document.querySelectorAll('.search, .ball , .f_bl , .s_bl , .searchbar');

btn.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {   
  for(var i = 0; i <= animatedEls.length-1; i++) {
    animatedEls[i].classList.add('paused');
  }
});

btn.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {   
  for(var i = 0; i <= animatedEls.length-1; i++) {
    animatedEls[i].classList.remove('paused');
  }
});
```

```css
.search {
   animation: colors_world 15s infinite
}  
.ball , .f_bl , .s_bl , .searchbar{
   animation: colors_world 15s infinite
}

.paused {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes colors {
  7.14%   {background: #E1140A;}
  21.43%  {background: #FF6A00;}
  35.71%  {background: #FEE600;}
  50%  {background: #6AC346;}
  64.27% {background: #46C8E1;}
  78.55% {background: #3E8DDD;}
  92.83% {background: #F04187;}
  116%   {background: #E1140A;}
}

@keyframes colors_world {
    7.14%   {color: #E1140A;}
    21.43%  {color: #FF6A00;}
    35.71%  {color: #FEE600;}
    50%  {color: #6AC346;}
    64.27% {color: #46C8E1;}
    78.55% {color: #3E8DDD;}
    92.83% {color: #F04187;}
    116%   {color: #E1140A;}
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <div class="ball_cont"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
  <div class="f_tr"></div>
  <div class="s_tr"></div>
  <div class="f_bl"></div>
  <div class="s_bl"></div>
</div>

<h1 class="hellosearch"> <span class="hello">hello</span><span class="search">search</span> </h1>

<form action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
  <input autofocus autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" placeholder="search..." class="bar">
  <input type="submit" value="Pesquisar" class="button_search">
</form>
```